# Hashing table design in C

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I have a design issue regarding HASH function.

In my program I am using a hash table of `size 2^13`, where the slot is calculated based on the value of the node(the hash key) which I want to insert.

Now, say my each node has two value `|A|B|` however I am inserting value into hash table using `A`.

Later on, I want to search a particular node which `B not A`.

Is it possible to that way? Is yes, could you highlight some design approaches?
The constraint is that I have to use `A` as the hash key.

Sorry, I can't share the code. Small example:

```
Value[] = {Part1, Part2, Part3};
insert(value)
check_for_index(value.part1)
```

`value.part1` to be used to calculate the index of the slot.

Once slot is found then insert the `"value"`

Later on,

```
search_in_hash(part2)

check_for_index("But here I need the value.part1 to check for slot index")
```

So, how can I relate the `part1, part2 & part3` such that I later on I can find the slot by either `part2 or part3`

If the problem statement is vague kindly let me know.

Comment: provide examples and code snippet. which hashtable implementation are you using?

Comment: hash key is a identifier of the value which you want to insert, so using B to search for A is not correct. Or you can design a magic hashing function making A and B same hash value.

Comment: I am confused why you insert with `part1` as hashing key, but find the slot by the key generated by other parts.Here is how hashing table works http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: @MYMNeo The process design is such that I have to insert the data using `part1` as key. It may happen that the search is done with any one of `part1, part2 or part3`. It is not mandatory to search with `part1` as the code wants to check whether `part2/3` are already in the table or not. Or is it associated with `part1` or not in the table.

Comment: Is there something stopping you from creating a hashtable per each part? Insert to all and just use the right instance for looking up using the specific part.

Comment: @viraptor Seems thats the last option for me. Have to bargain this search with memory consumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you intend to do a search element-by-element (in which case you don't need a hash, just a plain list), then what you basically ask is - can I have a hash such that hash(X) == hash(Y), but X!=Y, so that you could map to a location using part1 and then map to the same one using part2 or 3. That completely goes against what hashing stands for.

What you should do is (as viraptor also suggested), create 3 structures, each hashed using a different part of the value, and push the full value to all 3. Then when you need to search use the proper hash by the part you want to search by.

for e.g.:

```
value[] = {part1, part2, part3};
hash1.insert(part1, value)
hash2.insert(part2, value)
hash3.insert(part3, value)
```

then

```
hash2.search_in_hash(part2)
```

or

```
hash3.search_in_hash(part3)
```

The above 2 should produce the exact same values.

Also make sure that all data manipulations (removing values, changing them), is done on all 3 structures simultaneously. For e.g. -

```
value = hash2.search_in_hash(part2)
hash1.remove(value.part1)
hash2.remove(part2)        // you can assert that part2 == value.part2
hash3.remove(value.part3)
```

Comment: Thanks! I has this solution in mind but was thinking of a better way to handle it rather than sacrificing memory instead.

Comment: Well, that's the trade-off you should consider - using more memory helps you locate the elements faster, instead you can just search over your single hash key-by-key and match the part you want but didn't use as key. If, say 90% of lookups are done with a certain key it might be worthwhile. Also note that for space consideration, you can use a single structure, and have all 3 hashes point to it.